# How to add a row with countif in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, countif

I have a DataFrame with values 1 and 2.
I want to add a row in the end of the DataFrame, counting the number of 1 in each column. It should be similar
`COUNTIF(A:A,1)` and drag to all columns in excel

I tried something like `df.loc['lastrow']=df.count()[1]`, but the result is not correct.
How can I do it and what this function (`count()[1]`) does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `append` after `sum`

```
df.append(df.eq(1).sum(),ignore_index=True )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just compare your dataframe to the value you are interested in (`1` for example), and then perform a sum on these booleans, like:

```
>>> df
   0  1  2  3  4
0  2  2  2  1  2
1  2  2  2  2  2
2  2  1  2  1  1
3  1  2  2  1  1
4  2  2  1  2  1
5  2  2  2  2  2
6  1  1  1  1  2
7  2  2  1  1  1
8  1  1  1  2  1
9  2  2  1  2  1
>>> (df == 1).sum()
0    3
1    3
2    5
3    5
4    6
dtype: int64
```

You can thus *append* that row, like:

```
>>> df.append((df == 1).sum(), ignore_index=True)
    0  1  2  3  4
0   2  2  2  1  2
1   2  2  2  2  2
2   2  1  2  1  1
3   1  2  2  1  1
4   2  2  1  2  1
5   2  2  2  2  2
6   1  1  1  1  2
7   2  2  1  1  1
8   1  1  1  2  1
9   2  2  1  2  1
10  3  3  5  5  6
```

The last row here thus contains the number of `1`s of the previous rows.

Comment: A+ for the analysis.